# How to rename column on basis of condition in Polars python?

Tags: python-polars

I am trying to **rename column** on basis of a **condition** in `Polars python` but getting errors.

**Data:**

```
import polars as pl

test_df = pl.DataFrame({'Id': [100118647578,
  100023274028,100023274028,100023274028,100118647578,
  100118647578,100118647578,100023274028,100023274028,
  100023274028,100118647578,100118647578,100023274028,
  100118647578,100118647578,100118647578,100118647578,
  100118647578,100118647578,100023274028,100118647578,
  100118647578,100118647578,100118647578,100023274028,
  100118647578,100118647578,100118647578,100023274028,
  100118647578,100118647578,100023274028],

 'Age': [49,22,25,18,41,45,42,30,28,
  20,44,56,26,53,40,35,29,
  8,55,23,54,36,52,33,29,
  10,34,39,27,51,19,31],

 'Status': [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,2,1,1,
  1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,
  1,1,1,1,4]})
```

**Below code** is to **filter** the data on basis of value from argument and rename on same basis:

```
def Age_filter(status_filter_value = 1):
    return (
        test_df
        .filter(pl.col('Status') == status_filter_value)
        .sort(['Id','Age'])
        .groupby('Id')
        .agg( pl.col('Age').first())
        .sort('Id')

        # below part of code is giving error
        .rename({'Age' : pl.when(status_filter_value == 1)
                            .then('30_DPD_MOB')
                            .otherwise(pl.when(status_filter_value == 2)
                                       .then('60_DPD_MOB')
                                       .otherwise(pl.when(status_filter_value == 3)
                                                  .then('90_DPD_MOB')
                                                  .otherwise('120_DPD_MOB')
                                                  )
                                        )
                })
    )

Age_filter()
```

this gives an error: `TypeError: argument 'new': 'Expr' object cannot be converted to 'PyString'`

I have also tried **below code** but that is also not working:

```
def Age_filter1(status_filter_value = 1):
    {
    renamed_value = pl.when(status_filter_value == 1)
                            .then('30')
                            .otherwise(pl.when(status_filter_value == 2)
                                       .then('60')
                                       .otherwise(pl.when(status_filter_value == 3)
                                                  .then('90')
                                                  .otherwise('120')
                                                  )
                                        )


    return (
        test_df
        .filter(pl.col('Status') == status_filter_value)
        .sort(['Id','Age'])
        .groupby('Id')
        .agg( pl.col('Age').first())
        .sort('Id')
        .rename({'Age' : renamed_value
                })
    )
    }

Age_filter1()
```

Comment: rename doesn't take expressions: `rename(mapping: 'dict[str, str]')` - you would use regular python code to choose `renamed_value`

Comment: thanks @jqurious .. I will definitely try that as well !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, the [`rename`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rename.html#polars.DataFrame.rename) method takes a dict of string to string only. No complicated expressions needed - in fact, `pl.when`, etc. should also be taking expressions, not a static int value.

You can do something like this programmatically for your case:

```py
.rename({'Age' : f'{status_filter_value*30}_DPD_MOB')
```

EDIT: Or, per below comments, directly in the `agg`:

```py
.agg(pl.col('Age').first().alias(f'{status_filter_value*30}_DPD_MOB'))
```

Comment: Thanks @Wayoshi for sharing this code. This is indeed a smart way of writing it. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Apologies for being pedantic but `status_filter_value` isn't a boolean, it's an int. I think your point was that it doesn't take variables from the python environment.

Comment: Additionally, instead of using `rename` they should (or at least could) use `alias` like this `pl.col('Age').first().alias({'Age' : f'{status_filter_value*30}_DPD_MOB')` in their agg statement

Comment: Fixed the "boolean" part of the answer, thanks. As far as `alias`, I did think about that approach, is `rename` slower than `alias`?